# Create an array of business days

Tags: php, datetime, days

I need a method for creating an array of "business days" in PHP beteewn 2 dates.

For example:

```
getWorkingDays("2008-01-01","2009-06-30");
```

Will create an array like the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] ="2008-01-01",
    [1] ="2008-01-05",
    [2] ="2008-01-06",
    [3] ="2008-01-07",
    [4] ="2008-01-08",
    [5] ="2008-01-09",
    [6] ="2008-01-12",
    [7] ="2008-01-13",
    [8] ="2008-01-14",
    ...
)
```

Comment: what qualifies as a business day (just mon-fri, or are other days excluded too?)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest technique would be to create a loop from the starting date until the end date (you should covert both to timestamps via [mktime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) and then add a day (86400 seconds) to increment). In the inner part of the loop, you'd convert each date into a unix timestamp (once again via [mktime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php), etc.) and then use...

```
date('N', $dayStamp)
```

...to get the day of the week for the date in question.

As a basic implemention, this would look like:

```
<?php

    function getWorkingDays($startDate, $endDate) {

        $businessDays = array();
        $businessDaysInWeek = range(1,5);      // Only Monday to Friday

        // Decompose the provided dates.        
        list($startYear, $startMonth, $startDay) = explode('-', $startDate);
        list($endYear, $endMonth, $endDay) = explode('-', $endDate);

        // Create our start and end timestamps.
        $startStamp = mktime(1, 1, 1, $startMonth, $startDay, $startYear);
        $endStamp = mktime(1, 1, 1, $endMonth, $endDay, $endYear);

        // Check each day in turn.
        for($loop=$startStamp; $loop<=$endStamp; $loop+=86400) {
            if(in_array(date('N', $loop), $businessDaysInWeek)) {

                // You'll also want to omit bank holidays, etc. in here.

                $businessDays[] = date('Y-m-d', $loop);
            }
        }

        return $businessDays;
    }

    print_r(getWorkingDays('2011-01-10', '2011-01-24'));

?>
```

However, **you'll most likely also need to omit bank holidays**, etc. so you should store such exceptions in a database table/lookup array, etc. as check against them as appropriate.

Incidentally, if you're using a version of PHP earlier than 5.1.0, you should use `date('w'...` and adjust your days of week accordingly. (It counts from zero instead of one.)

Answer (score -1):

With the basics php date function you can make it, take the time to read the documentation at [PHP date](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php)